# Attempt to get Length of null Array of file.Length()

Tags: java, android

Please Help I am newbie and I am getting am getting this error?
while I start the App, I request for Storage Permission but after that the app crashes and gives me this error :- Attempt to get Length of null Array. Please Help.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techx.storysaver/com.techx.storysaver.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
      at com.techx.storysaver.ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageAdapter.java:40)
      at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:206)
      at com.techx.storysaver.ImageFragment.onCreateView(ImageFragment.java:53)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

This is my ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures/";
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();



    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

            return file.length;     //Line 40, Here i am gettin Error

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return file[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Glide
                .with( context )
                .load( file[position] )
                .into( imageView );
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(360,480));

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Here is my Image Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity())); //Line 50, Here Also i am getting Error



    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id",position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Bubletan , how did you align the code like that, what keystrokes u used?

Comment: @Remario What you mean? I used the editor.

Comment: i tried but it never properly align like that

Answer (score 2):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures/";
File f = new File(path);
File file[] = f.listFiles();
```

The `file[]` is null, therefore this statement `return file.length;` or any other involving that variable will fail. Also do use exception handling to handle files existence in your. Like FileNotFound for example.

Also try this `String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

```
String pic_path = String.format("%s/%s",path,specific_path);
```

Use this instead to get a handle to the file.

```
   File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

then `if(storageDir.exists()){File file[] = storageDir.listFiles();}`

Syntax for calling getExternalFilesDir, it depends on a context.

1. getActivity().getExternalFilesDir() in Fragment
2. context.getExternalFilesDir() in classes, where you pass Context
       as parameter
3. YourActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(); when
           called in inner class of Activity

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141904/discussion-on-answer-by-remario-attempt-to-get-length-of-null-array-of-file-leng).